# Laravel blade updated views not showing updated content

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to change input type password ,placeholder value.When i updated the placeholder value it's not showing .But it shows only the previous placeholder value.When page loading,it will show the new placeholder (1second) and then again switched into the previous value.

```
<div class="input-with-icon-left">
    <i class="icon-material-outline-lock"></i>
    <input type="password" class="input-text with-border"
     {{ (isset($customer) ? '' : 'required') }}  name="password"
     id="password" placeholder="Password of minimum 8 characters"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel caches the views after Blade is processed.

Run this command from terminal

```
php artisan view:clear
```